# Logcat shown Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 2.Login and registration form using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am a novice in php field here, currently I am working on a simple login and registration form for testing. But I get some errors, need some help from you all..tq

Below here is some of my code.. please help, thanks in advance

`loginform.php`:

```
<html>
<form action="signup.php"method="post">
    Username=<input type="text" name="n"></br>
    Password=<input type="password" name="p"></br>
    id<input type="text"name="id"></br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

`signup.php`:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db   = mysql_select_db("whatevershit_login","$conn");  
?>

<?php

    $user = $_POST['n'];
    $pass = $_POST['p'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql= "INSERT TO whatevershit_login value (".$id",'"$user"'','"$pass"')";

    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    #INSERT TO whatevershit_login value (
    #   1,
    #   'ken',
    #   'ken')
?>
```

and this is the error I get, but I still don't know why.. because I check all the syntax already.. maybe I could be wrong, but I don't know, so I hope can get you all help.. thank you..

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 2

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? It is `INSERT INTO` not `INSERT TO` also its `VALUES` instead of `VALUE`

Comment: Yea well you're doing it wrong.

Comment: i change "INSERT INTO" instead of "insert to",but the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 2" still appear..

Comment: Of course it still appears. Go read a better tutorial than the one you're following right now.

Comment: the error still the same..is it cause by other reason?? @Daan

Comment: Yes read the error message all the information is in there.

Comment: Obligatory http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One syntax error I can see is with the line.

```
$sql= "INSERT TO whatevershit_login value (".$id",'"$user"'','"$pass"')";
```

To correctly perform [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) it needs to read as follows.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO whatevershit_login VALUES (".$id.",'".$user."','".$pass."')";
```

With regards the error message I am assuming that you are getting the following.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 2.
```

This means that there is a colon character somewhere on line 2 of the file called signup.php. I'm guessing that the colon is at the end of the line and is a typo. In which case you just need to change it for a semi-colon **;**